# Time series : predictive model selection Index : will AIC do the trick?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, model-selection, model

I am currently modelizing the price of real-estate in France. I chose three type of models : an arima, an mce, a var ... i of course fitted them in the best way possible thourgh the usual prodecure (box-jenkins and such) ... NOW

I am (killing myself trying) to identify and index that would allow me to select the best model.

Currently reading the Model Selection and Multimodel Inference: A Practical Information- Theoretic Approach, Second Edition by Burnham & Anderson

but i get the feeling that this metric (AIC) is used to select "a model" ... well this is the issue actually. I am not trying to select the best model amongst (ie) different regressions (same instrument) ... but the best model between different instruments (arima, var, mce)

I of course can identify it graphically but i need to have a metric ?

Currently researching the AIC, BIC, HQ, RMSE, MAE, MAPE and studying the general Kullback et Leibler distance

but i have an issue whenever the litteratre states " selecting amongst differents models " ... because i have to select among different "instruments"

NB : i KNOW i'm not making any sense right now.

Comment: where can i find intel on formulas and how to perform, MdAPE, MdRAE and RMSE in R ? i found a meta study detailing the performance of error measurement techniques on wiki http://faculty.weatherhead.case.edu/Fred-Collopy/researchArticles/ErrorMeasures.pdf

Answer (score 0):

where can i find intel on formulas and how to perform, MdAPE, MdRAE and RMSE in R ? i found a meta study detailing the performance of error measurement techniques on wiki (year 1992) http://faculty.weatherhead.case.edu/Fred-Collop/researchArticles/ErrorMeasures.pdf

(chap 8 for results, chap 3 for definition of perf. criterias)